# How do I find all custom-created symbolic links in the entire system?

Tags: bash, search, symbolic-link

I've created several symbolic links in different places.

I can't really recall where each one of them is in the system and I've already removed programs they are associated with.

Is there a script / program / whatever that can search the entire system and remove any symlink which is custom-created?

Comment: You cannot distinguish between links that you created, and those the system created, unless all the links you created were owned by your user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have removed the associated/target programs, they should become broken. So it should be easy to search for broken symlinks:

```
find . -type l -exec sh -c "file -b {} | grep -q ^broken" \; -print
```

Change `.` for different search folder.

**Source:** [How can I find broken symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34248/how-can-i-find-broken-symlinks)

You can also filter using expected link name or target name instead of testing them.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -user "$USER" -type l`

Lists all symlinks under the current dir and subdirs created by your user. This also means created by a program your user (you) started, but if you can remember creating the listed symlink it should be fine. Verify the last access time if unsure. If you also want to follow the links, pass `-L`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to distinguish "custom-created" symlinks from "non-custom-created" symlinks.

If all of them were created without `sudo` / being root you may use this, which will output the full list of symbolic links owned by your user (which should be very short):

```
find / -xdev -user "$USER" -type l
```

Otherwise you're out of luck. I tried:

```
find / -xdev -type l
```

on my system and I got ~49000 results.

Comment: If me and all other users who needs this functionality have no luck on this in Ubuntu well never mind, its after all a small issue; Since most of them were not moved, I guess the apt-get purge will be enough to take care of this ...